# How can I add previous and next controls to the views slide show?

Tags: views

I have the photo slider on home page using views-slideshow. Now I need to add previous and next controls to that slider. How can I?

Answer (score 0):

I done it through css code, just follow [this steps](http://chrisshattuck.com/blog/how-use-images-next-and-previous-buttons-views-slideshow-or-how-replace-any-textual-link-image)

```
#views_slideshow_singleframe_prev_gallery-block_1, #views_slideshow_singleframe_next_gallery-block_1 {   width:71px;   height:0px;   padding-top:71px;   position:absolute;   top:100px;   overflow:hidden; } 

#views_slideshow_singleframe_prev_gallery-block_1 {   background:url('images/left-button-on.png');   left:0px; } 

#views_slideshow_singleframe_next_gallery-block_1 {   background:url('images/right-button-on.png');   right:0px; }

 #views_slideshow_singleframe_playpause_gallery-block_1 {   display:none; }
```

And also take a look at https://drupal.org/node/691984

Answer (score 0):

There is option for set the control for slideshow in views_slideshow module, you could select the slideshow control option while creation slideshow. but it provide only content control(Prev/ Next). If you need image for control button you could change this with css.